# Error when I trying to move a file in c# to an other folder with a listener on the first folder

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

Hello I have an error with file.Move a file to an other file with a listener to this specific folder,
I want move the file in Archive folder when a new file incomming on the folder Pending.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListenApp
{
    class Program
    {

        public static class Globals
        {

            public static string args = "//lux.pbk/Profiles/LUX/BI14H/ProfilADW7/Desktop/trade/Pending/";
            public static string archivePath = "//lux.pbk/Profiles/LUX/BI14H/ProfilADW7/Desktop/trade/archive/";



        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Run();
        }

        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        private static void Run()
        {
        
            /* // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
             if (args.Length != 2)
             {
                 // Display the proper way to call the program.
                 Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
                 return;
             }*/

            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
            using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
            {
                watcher.Path = Globals.args;

                // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
                // the renaming of files or directories.
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                     | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                     | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                     | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

                // Only watch text files.
                watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

                // Add event handlers.
               
                watcher.Created += OnChanged;
              

                // Begin watching.
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                // Wait for the user to quit the program.
                Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
                while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
            }
        }

        // Define the event handlers.
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
            Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
            
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name);

            if(File.Exists(Globals.args + e.Name))
            {
                File.Move(Globals.args + e.Name, Globals.archivePath + e.Name);   // System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'
            }
            
            

           
            
            
        }
            

       
    }
}
```

On File.Move, I have a error, that said :

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it
> is being used by another process.'

How fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your program is the only one that has this file opened?
You can check that using free tool such as Sysinternals Process Explorer (Find - Find Handle or DLL).

Comment: The way to fix it is to make sure no other processes are accessing the file at the same time

Comment: How big are these files? Would it be possible that some other process is still writing/reading to/from this file or changing it when you receive OnChanged event?

Comment: Yes, I'm sur they don't have opened .txt on the compter.( I have restart the computer to be sure)